# How to add multiple workspaces in app through yarn workspaces

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I'm creating an app which depends on a module. File structure of the application is...

```
demo-app
|
|----package.json("workspaces": ["module-core/packages/*","src/packages/*" ])
|----src/
|    |---packages/
|        |---package.json ("workspaces": ["packages/*"])
|        |---module-a
|            |---package.json("name":"@app/module-a","private":true, "workspaces": ["packages/*"])
|        |---module-b
|            |---package.json("name":"@app/module-b","private":true, "workspaces": ["packages/*"])
|
|----module-core/
|    |---package.json ("workspaces": ["packages/*"])
|    |---packages/
|        |---core-a
|            |---package.json("name":"@app/core-a","private":true, "workspaces": ["packages/*"])
|        |---core-b
|            |---package.json("name":"@app/core-b","private":true, "workspaces": ["packages/*"])
```

Here,
**`@app/module-a`** is dependent on **`@app/core-a`** and **`@app/module-b`** is dependent on **`@app/core-b`**.

I created a workspace in the demo app **`"workspaces": ["module-core/packages/*","src/packages/*"]`**.

When running `yarn install` it a prompt error `Couldn't find package "@app/module-a@^0.0.0" required by "@app/module-a@0.1.0" on the "npm" registry`.

is it missing in workspace management?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm able to build the workspace just enabling the property `"private":true`

**file: demo-app/package.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["module-core/packages/*","src/packages/*"]
  ......
  ......
}
```

**Note**: Order of packages in the workspaces are important.